# Static function as operand

Tags: c++, eclipse, optimization, arduino

I have made some static functions in order to call them without making any object of the class they belong to. I have included the header file of the class with the static functions (NTP.h) into another class (DayNumber).

I want to place the returns of some functions as operants of a functions of DayNumber class. I get error that NTP has not been declared. Here it is the code.

Header file:

```
#include "NTP.h"

class DayNumber{
    private:
        int _day1YearLoop[];
        int _day4YearLoop[];

    public:
        int Days1YearLoop;
        int Days4YearLoop;

        DayNumber();
        void dayNumberCalc( NTP::getYear(),NTP::getMonth(),NTP::getDate());
        virtual ~DayNumber();

        bool checkLeapYear(int setYear);
};

#endif
```

Implementation .cpp file(part of it):

```
void DayNumber::dayNumberCalc( NTP::getYear(), NTP::getMonth(), NTP::getDate()){
    int setYear = NTP::getYear();
    int setMonth = NTP::getMonth();
    int setDay = NTP::getDate();
    //Days that passed from the beginning of the year for the first day each month
    int _day1YearLoop[] = {0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334};
    //i= _day1YearLoop;

    //Days that passed from the beginning of the second year since the 'for'.
    //The first day of the running year in a four-years loop.
    int _day4YearLoop[]={366,731,1096};

    if (checkLeapYear(setYear)){
        if (setMonth>2){ //Diorthwsi gia ton mina flebari
            Days1YearLoop = *(_day1YearLoop + (setMonth-1)) + setDay + 1;
            Days4YearLoop = Days1YearLoop;
        }
        else{
            Days1YearLoop = *(_day1YearLoop+(setMonth-1))+setDay;
```

Why is that happening? Isn't it supposed to work this way?

Also inside the function dayNumberCalc should I save the returns of the static functions in local variables and use them instead of the returns?

Comment: I hardly doubt that you can use method-calls as arguments when declaring your class. It looks, sorry, silly... Apart from that, WHERE do you get the error that you did not include NTP? Did you include NTP.h in the .cpp-file?

Comment: no i haven't until now. i though that if i include it in header file since i am including the header file of the class  in the .cpp file all the headers that are included in this file are included to the .cpp file. Except that nothing happend.

Comment: Look at sftrabbit's suggestion. It looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for your function declaration is incorrect:

```
void dayNumberCalc( NTP::getYear(),NTP::getMonth(),NTP::getDate());
```

You're supposed to list the argument types and names here. Perhaps you wanted:

```
void dayNumberCalc(int year, int month, int day);
```

Then you would call it with:

```
dayNumber.dayNumberCalc(NTP::getYear(),NTP::getMonth(),NTP::getDate());
```

Alternatively, if you want the static members of `NTP` to be called from within `dayNumberCalc`, give it no arguments:

```
void dayNumberCalc();
```

Or, if you want to have arguments that have default values given by the static functions, do:

```
void dayNumberCalc(int year = NTP::getYear(), int month = NTP::getMonth(),
                   int day = NTP::getDate());
```